# How to authenticate using JWT by ajax?

Tags: authentication

As WordPress REST API Doc said, the authentication by for REST API can be done by JWT (https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)

The recommended plugin in the documentation is [JWT Authentication for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/), but this plugin has not been updated for 1 year.

My question is, is this plugin still safe to use? if not, how can I auth using JWT by ajax?

Comment: You can use other plugin like [Application Passwords](https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/), or [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-authentication/) if you must use JWT. But if you're making the API request within the same domain, then you can just use the default cookie authentication.

Comment: Plugins that have a single purpose like that rarely require updates. If it does the job, it does the job, and nothing major has changed in the REST API lately that would require an update. I wouldn't worry to much about the lack of updates.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you! it really helps. What I'm doing is a mobile application.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I agreed with you, I jest need to make sure that plugin is not out of date yet.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ, I'm using https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-authentication/, it's working for me